# Отслеживания новых твитов конкретного пользователя Python

Tags: python

Хочу сделать монитор на python, который бы следил за пользователем twitter и при наличии новых твитов от него отправлял их мне, например через Discord или Telegram. Как я понял нужно использовать tweepy но ответов на мой вопрос я так и не нашел, может кто-то занимался подобным проектом и сможет помочь, заранее спасибо!

Comment: а код у вас есть?

Comment: а в чём вопрос ? 'какой модуль использовать ?'

Comment: Кода нет, потому что я не особо понял какие модули и библиотеки использовать, хотел бы пообщаться с человеком, который работал с твиттером